# List has no rows for assignment to SObject error on null check

Tags: apex, trigger, queryexception

Salesforce noob here.

I have got an apex trigger that is erroring with "**System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject**" and after researching for quite a bit, I don't understand why the error is being thrown.

In theory, from what I have gathered, that error is caused when trying to assign a variable to the result of a query that returns nothing. One thing I read was that empty arrays/lists won't throw this error and we can perform an empty or size check before trying to use the array/list.

I think I am doing that but there must be something I am surely missing.

```
for(Lead lead: leads) {
...
  if (lead.ConvertedAccountId != null) {  
  Account[] accs = [SELECT Id, V_Count__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :lead.ConvertedAccountId LIMIT 1];
                if (accs.size() > 0) {
...
```

The error is thrown at the `if` line or the next one down, as I am not sure the line numbers take into account the first line where I am creating the trigger, eg,

```
trigger myTrigger on Lead (before update) {
```

**EDIT**

Adding the whole code of the trigger:

```
trigger myTrigger on Lead (before update) {
    List<Lead> leads = System.Trigger.new;
    List<V__c> vList = [SELECT Id, Lead__c FROM V__c WHERE V__c.Lead__c IN :Trigger.new];
    List<V__c> vsToUpdate = new List<V__c>{};
    for(Lead lead: leads) {
        if (lead.IsConverted) {
            
            double vCount = 0; 
            for (V__c vis: vList) {
                vCount = vCount + 1;
                if (vis.Lead__c == lead.iD) {
                    vis.Lead__c = null;
                    vis.Account__c = lead.ConvertedAccountId;
                    vsToUpdate.add(vis);
                }
            }           
           
            if (lead.ConvertedAccountId != null) {
                Account[] accs = [SELECT Id, LV__V_Count__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :lead.ConvertedAccountId LIMIT 1];
                if (accs.size() > 0) {
                    if(vCount != accs[0].LV__V_Count__c) {
                        accs[0].LV__V_Count__c = vCount;
                        update accs[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    update vsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: You do not seem to have included the code that actually throws the error. Somewhere, you are assigning a query result to a single SObject.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, well, I would assume so too but the error is thrown at line 20, which is the `if` one in the code I put there. I can paste the whole trigger if that helps

Comment: That is not possible. The error can only be thrown on a line where you assign a query result.

Comment: So I am guessing it is on the next line down, where the accs array is being assigned. As I said on the question, I assume the line numbers exclude the first line where the trigger is initialized. But even then, if the query returns an empty list, an empty array should be created fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you use `Developer Console` or any IDE, it should give you accurate line numbers. But as the lines you have identified can't be responsible, you should just include the whole trigger at this point (assuming it s not prohibitively large).

Comment: @AdrianLarson, added the whole trigger to the question body

Comment: Try to execute this code again and see if you are still getting same error.

Comment: I am unable to debug it but it last occurred in late November. The trigger was last updated a year ago so this is the code that occasionally throws the error

Comment: Even seeing the full trigger, there's no possible way the error you're getting can be thrown by the trigger you have on `Lead`. Setting aside your query + dml inside of a for loop (which is bad practice), it's possible that you're getting this error from a trigger on `Account` or `V__c`. If you have the stack trace, that'd be the fastest way to figure out where the error is actually happening.